# How do I sort the Facebook News Feed

Tags: iphone, facebook

**EDIT:** As of Facebook v10.0, this question received a lot more views as the option has moved again.  See the new answer below.

#### Original Question

I'm using Facebook v6.8 on iPhone 4 running iOS 7.0.4.

In previous versions of Facebook, I could tap a cog icon in the NewsFeed box and select whether to sort by Top Stories or Most Recent.  I can't find that icon any more.

How can I sort by Most Recent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst at the top of your feed, pull down so you see the News Feed button. Tap that and you can select from All Friends, Most Recent. Lots of other choices are available if you expand the list by tapping the downward facing arrow.

[image]

Comment: I could have sworn that option wasn't there earlier today. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As of Facebook v10.0, this option has moved again.  Tap **More**, then the drop-down next to **Feeds** and find **Most Recent** hidden among the options.

[image: Most Recent]